# Multiple functions in one graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

So, I have a numpy.ndarray called CT with shape (10, 500).

Each row is a function and defined over the x-variables called Gm. Gm is a numpy.ndarray with shape (1,500).

I need to graph the 10 functions in the CT matrix (as a function of Gm) in one graph and try the following:

```
# consumption functions over time    
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

TimeSteps = CT.shape[0]

for t in range(0,TimeSteps):
    plt.plot(Gm,CT[t].reshape(1,DiscG),'go',label='t')
plt.show()
```

This works, but all graphs are shown with the same color (green) and it is not possible to distinguish if the graph is t = 0, 1, 2, etc.

Any idea as to how you get plt to choose a different color for each graph and make it possible to label them and put it in a text box.

Comment: your line spec is 'go' which is green with 'o' marker, remove the 'g' and it will be different colors. See more at the matplotlib docs

Comment: For the "text box", I assume you mean legend? If so, make `label=t` and then call `plt.legend()` after the loop

Comment: regarding the color @GlobalTraveler ... replacing the 'go' with 'o' does not create a unique color for each graph. Rather, it looks like different points on the graph (in certain intervals) have different color. So, still indistinguishable.

Comment: @terman the points are probably overlapping creating a seemingly non-difference, you can adjust the alpha value for sanity checks or use different subplots.

Comment: legend ... @DavidG ... I tried to do so, but was left with a traceback ... ValueError: Image size of 595x70022 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.... looks like it might be related with the issue regarding the color ...

Comment: @terman no the legend is not the issue , the issue is related to your fig size, not sure on the dimensions but i assume your legend is too large for the figure.

Comment: A [mcve] would help to show what the issue might be

Comment: OK, so I have a CT matrix of shape (2,10):array([[0.        , 0.22222222, 0.44444444, 0.66666667, 0.88888889,
        1.11111111, 1.33333333, 1.55555556, 1.77777778, 2.        ],
       [0.        , 0.22222222, 0.44444444, 0.66666667, 0.88888889,
        1.06621773, 1.14478114, 1.30415264, 1.3647587 , 1.51515152]]) and Gm = array([[0.        , 0.22222222, 0.44444444, 0.66666667, 0.88888889,
        1.11111111, 1.33333333, 1.55555556, 1.77777778, 2.        ]]). When I run the above with color option 'o' instead of 'go' I get a different color for specific x-values.

Comment: In the above DiscG is 10.

Answer (score 0):

It is common curtosy when asking a question to have a [minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The questions you posed  as problems are actually examples of the code working as intended but not as you want them to be. Here is an example of scatter dots with different colors and different labels as you posed on your question and answered by me and @DavidG.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# dummy data
x = np.random.rand(10, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
[ax.plot(xi, marker = 'o', label = idx) for idx, xi in enumerate(x)]
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

The color cycles here stem from the standard color map used by matplotlib if you want to use specific colors or change the standard cycles please look at the documentation provided by [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

Answer (score 0):

OK - found another simpler way ... simply to transpose the input:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(Gm.transpose(),CT.transpose(),marker='o')
plt.show()
```

That way the whole function gets a unique color, and it seems resolved. So my initial guess running a for loop was too complicated.